# Guzzle add CSRF token

Tags: php, drupal, token, csrf, guzzle

I am trying to create a product in drupal commerce using guzzle and restful webservices.

When i am trying to create a new product i use the following process:
 1) Login as a user who has the rights to create a product (succes)
 2) Request CSRF token (succes)
 3) Create product : Uh oh!: Client error response [status code] 401 [reason phrase] Unauthorized: Access to this operation not granted

Now when i am doing this process trough poster (Firfox add-on). I can succesfully create a product, but it guzzle i always fail to acces this operation.

```
require 'guzzle.phar';
use Guzzle\Http\Client;
//EDIT:
use Guzzle\Plugin\Cookie\CookiePlugin;
use Guzzle\Plugin\Cookie\CookieJar\ArrayCookieJar;

$client = new Client('http://localhost:8888/drupal-test/');

//EDIT:
$cookiePlugin = new CookiePlugin(new FileCookieJar($cookie_file_name));
$client->addSubscriber($cookiePlugin);

//User login
$request = $client->post('my_services/user/login.json', null,
                    array(
                            'username' => 'its',
                            'password' => '****'
                    ));

$response_json = $response->getBody();
$session = $response_var->session_name . '=' . $response_var->sessid;

//Services CSRF token
$request = $client->get('services/session/token');
$response = $request->send();
$token = $response->getBody(TRUE);


//Create Product
$request = $client->post('my_services/product.json',
        array(
            'X-CSRF-Token' => $token,
         ),
        array(
            'sku' => 'guzzleproductadd10',
            'title' => 'guzzleproductadd10',
            'type' => 'product',
            'commerce_price_amount' => '200',
            'commerce_price_currency_code' => 'EUR'
        )
 );
//$request->addHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $token);
try {
     $response = $request->send();
} 
catch (Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Uh oh!: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I don't really see what i am doing wrong. I logged in, added the required variables to the header.

Ty!

Edit: solution see comments. I adjusted  the code.

Comment: What you've got in `$session` needs to be sent as a cookie, not as a plain-text header. Basic cURL example [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79497/new-user-registration-sequence-for-services-3-4), with a bit of Googling should be easy to convert that logic to use Guzzle

Comment: You where right, i adjusted the code! thx