# Using Goutte / Guzzle with Laravel to Submit Form with CSRF

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, goutte

I have two websites (both mine) and I am testing Guzzle.

I am trying to submit a search form.  This search form has the standard Laravel CSRF token hidden field automatically generated "_token".

When submitting the field with goutte it gets an error.  Checking my logs on the website I can see it is the Laravel "TokenMismatchException"

Do I need to do something special in goutte to make sure it is posting the auto generated "_token" hidden field?

Comment: if you're happy with my answer below, you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable CSRF protection for that route.

In `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` add this code to beginning of `handle()` method:

```
$openRoutes = ['free/route', 'free/too'];

foreach($openRoutes as $route) {
    if ($request->is($route)) {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's an option.  In this situation, CSRF really isn't needed on a regular search form.  But in the future, what if I was attempting to log into my website, and didn't want to disable the token, what are my options then?  I had assumed that since the field is pre populated that it would just be submitted with the search field itself.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you don't have to worry as with this code you disable CSRF protection only for that route. On other forms CSRF protection will work as usual.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, what if I want to use Goutte/Guzzle to login, without removing CSRF (instead of just doing a simple search like above)

Comment: You can login with CSRF token using Guzzle, but it a little more complicated task, you can find example here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22756009/1331425

Answer (score 2):

As of Laravel 5.1, in `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` you can disable CSRF protection by adding the concerned route to the `$except` array. Like so:

```
protected $except = [
    '/api/v1/list', //This route won't have CSRF protection
];
```